# show multiple images in different window in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I want to display multiple images in different windows separately in OpenCV with C API. Following is my code, where I have done a for loop to show the same image multiple times until the loop rotates. Can anybody tell me why my code is crashing after showing only the first image? Following is my code for loop:

```
for(x = 0; x <= 5;x++)
{ 

     IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), src->depth, 3);
     IplImage* dstRGB[3];

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         rgb[i] = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), src->depth, 1);
         dstRGB[i] = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), src->depth, 1);
     }

     cvSplit(src, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], NULL);

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         cvFilter2D(rgb[i], dstRGB[i], rgb2);
     }

     cvReleaseMat(&rgb2);
     cvMerge(dstRGB[0], dstRGB[1], dstRGB[2], NULL, dst);

     cvNamedWindow("dst", 1);
     cvShowImage("dst", dst);

     //cvSaveImage("output.png", dst); 

     cvReleaseImage(&dst);

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         cvReleaseImage(&rgb[i]);
         cvReleaseImage(&dstRGB[i]);
     }

     cvWaitKey(0);
     } // for loop ends

     cvReleaseImage(&src);

     cvDestroyWindow(argv[5]);
     cvDestroyWindow("dst");
```

Following is the error it shows after displaying the first image

```
   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (anchor.inside(Rect(0, 0, ksize.width, ksize.height))) in normalizeAnchor, file /home/Documents/opencv-2.4.5/release/modules/imgproc/precomp.hpp, line 90 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /home/ocuments/opencv-2.4.5/release/modules/imgproc/precomp.hpp:90: error: (-215) anchor.inside(Rect(0, 0, ksize.width, ksize.height)) in function normalizeAnchor Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Also please rename anything with "rgb" to "bgr".

Comment: please put your complete code, this way we maybe we can fix it

Comment: @Khashayar please seemy new question with a simpler code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851743/i-want-to-display-output-image-in-different-windows

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start fixing your main loop

```
for(x = 0; x = 5;x++)
```

possibly into

```
for(x = 0; x != 5; x++)
```

As it is, it is an endless loop

Comment: I edited my for loop with <= sign but still it's crashing after showing first image..please see the update on the question and on the code

Comment: At which line does it crash?

Comment: plase see my  updated question I have showed the error it's showing after displaying the first image