# I want to display output image in different windows in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I want to display the same image multiple times in different windows, for which I have used a for loop but I am getting only one window display. Can anybody provide me any suggestion on how to display output images in multiple windows? Following is the code in OpenCV with C API. Here, I am simply loading an image from argv[1] and trying to display it in 4 different windows.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
int i;
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1],1);
cvMoveWindow("Example1", 100, 100);
cvNamedWindow( "Example1", 1);
for(i =0; i<=4;i++) // for loop to display the same image in 4 different windows
{
 cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
}
cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseImage( &img );
cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
}
```

P.S. I have asked a similar question [show multiple images in different window in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834397/show-multiple-images-in-different-window-in-opencv) before which was not solved and the code was difficult to understand so I am trying this question with a simpler code.

Comment: saw you comment! writing the code now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
int i;
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("/home/khashayar/Downloads/bug14.png", 1);
cvMoveWindow("Example1", 100, 100);
cvNamedWindow("Example1", 1);
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
{
    char str[5] = "test";
    str[4] = i+48;
    cvShowImage(str, img);
}
cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
```

Comment: your code have mixed C and C++. It's showing me so many errors

Comment: char str[5] = "test"; str[4] = i+48;

Comment: it creates a char* which contains "test" and a number. to put the number in char you should use their ascii code,ascii code for 0 is 48. so we plus the number with 48 to get the right ascii for the number we want. it will result in test0,test1, ...

Comment: do you know how can I save the same image in different names, as I was displaying in different windows with the command cvSaveImage("out.ppm", dst); how can I cange the name of "out.ppm" so that it gets saved in different names

Comment: same way use char str[8] = "out"; str[3] = i+48; str[4] ='.'; str[5] ='p'; str[6] ='p'; str[7] ='m';

Comment: but I really suggest to use c++; and it is much easier also for performance use Mat instead of IplImage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34140/discussion-between-user2567857-and-khashayar)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i =0; i<=4;i++) //  hmm, i<=4 will actually run 5 times ...
{
 cvShowImage( "Example1", img );  // <-- same window name for all == only 1 shown
}
```

but, *please* discard the c api and use c++ !. *please* !

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread( argv[1],1);
    for( int i=0; i<4; i++ ) // for loop to display the same image in 4 different windows
    {
       cv::String name = cv::format("Example%d",i);
       cv::namedWindow( name, 1);
       cv::imshow( name, img );
    }
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```